# How do I automatically select a different cell when the user enters a value?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have formatted a worksheet to need input in only specific cells.  I'm wondering if it is possible to add VBA code such that when the user enters a value in cell A5 that the code automatically selects G5.  When the user enters a value in G5, the code should automatically select A6.

Comment: (1) Protect your sheet and allow only to edit cells in col A and G. (2) Use the `Change`-Event of the Worksheet and check the address of the modified cell

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a small bit of VBA code in the worksheet module of the worksheet you want to behave in this manner.

Open up the Visual Basic Editor and double-click the name of the worksheet you are interested in modifying under "Microsoft Excel Objects" As seen here:

[image]

Then paste in the following code so the module appears as in the picture.  The "Option Explicit" directive at the top is optional.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then Range("G5").Select
End Sub
```

This code says:  When ever a change is made to the worksheet, if the cell changed was "A5" then select G5

Comment: This appears to be working Gove! Thank you kindly! What if we need to repeat the same A6 to G6, A7 to G7, etc.? As soon as G6 is completed, it should go on to A7!

Comment: It looks as though an administrator has closed this question.  Please post another one and I'll answer it.  Once you have posted, put a comment here so I can be notified.  Can you accept this answer?

Comment: Thank you, Gove. Thank you so much for your assistance! When I ask the question again, I'll leave a comment on this post. By the way, I've updated the question. I'm not sure if you may comment now or not.

Comment: Hello, Gove! I hope you're doing well. I've posted the question. Please let me know if you see the new question and can help!

Comment: I just looked and it seems that funThomas gave you a really good answer.

Comment: Yes, I've double-checked it. It is fully functional. Thanks